# Docker container connection timeout while installing packages

Tags: docker

I'm having some trouble installing some packages.

The command is:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends libkrb5-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The error is:

> E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/krb5/libkadm5clnt-mit12_1.18.3-6%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 146.75.62.132 80]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
>
> ERROR: Service 'webserver' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends libkrb5-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100

The connection works well and I'm able to install other packages.
This morning I was also able to build the same image correctly but suddenly it started to give me that error. Always with the same package.

Yesterday I had the same problem with other packages, but I managed to solve them by splitting the installation into different rows.

I'm having this problem with different packages every now and then and I'm 100% sure that is not a connection problem. If I add more packages before it always fails on the same package.

I tried to ping the IP from another container and it works. I also tried to open the link to download the file and everything works fine.

I always build it with the --no-cache option.

This is the complete Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache-bullseye as php


# PhpUnit 8 (Version 9 doesn' support php 7.2)
# Install phpunit, the tool that we will use for testing
RUN curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/phpunit "https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-9.phar" && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends zip && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends sqlite3 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends libpng-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing --no-install-recommends libc-client-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing --no-install-recommends libldap2-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends libcap2-bin && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends libldb-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq --fix-missing && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends memcached libmemcached-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-configure mysql && docker-php-ext-install mysql  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd && docker-php-ext-install gd  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure curl && docker-php-ext-install curl  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && docker-php-ext-install imap  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure xml && docker-php-ext-install xml  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure soap && docker-php-ext-install soap  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure bcmath && docker-php-ext-install bcmath  \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap && docker-php-ext-install ldap

RUN pecl install igbinary && docker-php-ext-enable igbinary
RUN pecl install -o -f redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
RUN pecl install -o -f msgpack && docker-php-ext-enable msgpack
RUN pecl install -o -f memcached && docker-php-ext-enable memcached
RUN pecl install -o -f pcov && docker-php-ext-enable pcov
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: have you tried using docker-compose?

Comment: The apt get install part works pretty fine for me. This should be an issue with your internet, try switiching to a different newtork or use proxy incase you are on a restricted traffic server.

Comment: @FadiAkkad yes, I tried, always with --no-cache option

Comment: @RajaRavindra it could be something related to the connection between the docker service and the host? I'm on Debian 11

Comment: No I dont think so, it has to be your internet solely that host i using. Might be a restricted one or something. Have you tried switching the connection?

Comment: @Freedev did you resolve this?

Comment: @S1r-Lanzelot unfortunately not. Every time I have to re-build a container I have to try many times until it works.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same time out error when trying to install texlive on docker, what help to circumvent this issue was modifying the apt config ([docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html)), like so:

```bash
RUN echo '\
Acquire::Retries "100";\
Acquire::https::Timeout "240";\
Acquire::http::Timeout "240";\
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";\
APT::Install-Recommends "false";\
APT::Install-Suggests "false";\
Debug::Acquire::https "true";\
' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom
```

It's kinda late to the party, but I hope it helps ;)